Unable to install module "auth_ldap" because an external dependency is not met: Python library not installed: ldap
i already installed pip install python-ldap but the error persist im not sure if its working into windows might someone here's know how to fix the issue for odoo v16 using windows
i already installed everything just to fix the error but isnt working
here's the error
Unable to install module "auth_ldap" because an external dependency is not met: Python library not installed: ldap

Show us the exact command you used, and the full error message.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sorry for the confusion here's the error i have right now
Unable to install module "auth_ldap" because an external dependency is not met: Python library not installed: ldap
im using the windows and version 16 odoo

Put this line in the requirements.txt (located inside the directory for custom modules):
python-ldap==3.3.1

You have to install the python package ldap before installing the auth_ldap module (https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/installing.html):
pip3 install python-ldap

Using python 3.8 and system 64, run the command:
pip install --only-binary :all: "C:\python_ldap-3.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"

With an Odoo installation using exe, you can find the path of your python.exe:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 16.0\python\Scripts 

Then run the command:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 16.0\python\Scripts"
python.exe --version
pip.exe install --only-binary :all: WHL_FILE_PATH


got this error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

answer updated... Try installing a different version (python-ldap==3.3.1) ...and have a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482382/error-seen-during-pip-install-python-ldap
